# memory error while computing the eigen vectors of covariance matrix

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, memory, pca

While implementing the PCA using a dataset of 160 samples and each has 8970 dimension. An exception is thrown stating `memory error` while computing the co-variance matrix:

```
CovarianceMatrix=np.matmul(AdjustedData.T,AdjustedData)/(DataSize-1)
```

I have also tried to do matrix multiplication by hand (without using numpy) and got this error fixed but again I encountered another memory error in eigVectors computations by `numpy.linalg.eig`

I have 8GB RAM and I use pycharm which consumes 700 MG before 
raising the "memory error".

Here is the full code for the PCA computation:

```
def ImplementPCA(InputData,OutputDimension):
    INPUTDATA=np.array(InputData)
    Mean=INPUTDATA.mean(axis=0)
    AdjustedData=InputData-Mean
    AdjustedDataT=AdjustedData.T
    DATASize=len(AdjustedData)
    CoverianceMatrix=[]
    for i in range(0,len(AdjustedDataT)):
       CoverianceMatrix.append(np.matmul(AdjustedDataT[i],AdjustedData)/DATASize-1)
    eigVls,eigVecs= LA.eig(CoverianceMatrix)

    idx = eigenValues.argsort()[::-1]
    eigenValues = eigenValues[idx]
    eigenVectors = eigenVectors[:, idx]
    eigenVectors=eigenVectors*-1
    eigenVectors=eigenVectors.T
    eigenVectors=eigenVectors[:OutputDimension]
    eigenVectors=eigenVectors.T
    Y=np.matmul(INPUTDATA,eigenVectors)
    return Y
```

Hope you can give guide me in this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `svd` (directly on `AdjustedData`) instead of `eig`.

Comment: with using (svd) the output eigen vectors matrix cells  are  zeros !